# Evaluation order while assigning to a class field

Tags: java

I have a very basic question regarding the inner workings or java.
lets say we have a following statement

```
e.fld = expr;
```

where e is some class having a field  fld. and expr is any java expression.

My question is that whether expr will be evaluated first or e will be evaluated first.

Comment: This seems like an easy enough thing to just test

Comment: Java always evaluates expressions from left to right, so `e` is first.

Comment: Java Language Spec, [§15.26](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-Assignment): the expression on the left-hand size is evaluated before the expression on the right-hand side.

Comment: thank you. that answered my question. I completely forgot 'e.fld = expr' itself is also an expression.